# What prompted the Heroes of the Lance to start searching for the True Gods of Krynn?

Tags: dragonlance

From what I remember, the Companions (as they were called before they got the first Dragonlance?) or Heroes of the Lance had left for five years in search for signs of the True Gods of Krynn. The first published novel, "Dragons of Autumn Twilight" shows them reconvening after their search. I know the True Gods were gone since the Cataclysm 300 years prior, but what set the heroes off in the first place? Was that ever established?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The story is included in [*Leaves from the Inn of the Last Home*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0880384654) (in "The Separation" in the "How the Companions Met" section), although an earlier version was published in *Dragons of Mystery* (a Dragonlance RPG module).

It's not a particularly long section of the book, and it basically just explains that they realise that they have reached the end of the fairly carefree days adventuring together and all have different goals they want to achieve. Their purpose wasn't specifically to look for the gods:

- **Sturm** was moving along with his plan to become a knight
- **Kitiara** was most likely looking for more information about her father (but found the Dragonlords instead)
- **Tanis** was troubled by his feelings for Kitiara and Laurana and wanted time to think about things
- **Raistlin** was leaving to take the Test (and so of course **Caramon** was going with him)
- **Tasslehoff** didn't really have any specific plans (naturally), but said he might look into his family
- **Flint** intended to check out rumours of problems in his homeland
- **Tika** (not then a companion, of course) is featured as a kid working in the Inn

They plan to meet back at the Inn each year on that date if they can, and vow that in five years they will all be there.

The *Preludes* / *Preludes II* novels cover their adventures between this point and the start of *Autumn Twilight*.  (I gather than some of this material is later ret-con'd out, but I'm not particularly familiar with the story from the mid '90's onwards; I presume their original reasons for separating stay the same).

**Riverwind**, not an original companion, was on a search to find out about the true gods (also covered in one of the *Preludes II* books).

Comment: I'm assuming some of the sillier bits, like going to one of the moons, are part of the ret-con...

Comment: The preludes are terrible ( like all prequels) and completely contradict things in the original trilogy ( they are of course written by other authors). The only books/tales I consider 'canon' are the ones by Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman (but even they retcon stuff now and then)